# Django : ManyToMany, Who is the most efficient?

Tags: django, django-models

I hesitate between two conceptions of my models.

In my website, there are football teams. These teams contains coachs, players, directors... etc.

Currently, I modeled this like that (1) :

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25,primary_key=True)

class Chief(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, null=False,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Player(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, null=False,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=30) #3 positions posible

class Director(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, null=False,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The problem is when I want to get all members of a team (chiefs, directors and players), I have to execute 3 requests.
But the advantage is when I want just all directors, I just search in Director entity !

I hesitate to delete these 3 models (Director, Player and Chief) and make 3 relations ManyToMany in Team like that (2) :

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25,primary_key=True)
    chiefs = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    directors = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    players_position1 = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    players_position2 = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    players_position3 = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

**Which is the most efficient way between the (1) and the (2) ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [model inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance)

**models.py**

```
class TeamMember(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, null=False,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Chief(TeamMember):
    pass

class Director(TeamMember):
    pass

class Player(TeamMember):
    position = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

**views.py**

```
#Get all members
members = TeamMember.objects.all()

#Only players
players = Player.objects.all()
```

Comment: But I will have repetition of many data no ? Because TeamMember is not abstract, so this model will contains same information like Chief model for example ...

Comment: No. Table <appname>_chief will have only one column - teammeber_ptr.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25,primary_key=True)

class MemberQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def chiefs(self):
        return self.filter(position='a')

    def directors(self):
        return self.filter(position='b')

    def players(self):
        return self.filter(position__in=['c', 'd', 'e'])

class Member(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, models.CASCADE, related_name="members")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, models.CASCADE)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=(
        ('a', 'chief'),
        ('b', 'director'), 
        ('c', 'player position 1'),
        ('d', 'player position 2'),
        ('e', 'player position 3'))

    objects = MemberQuerySet.as_manager()
```

Now you can get all members of a team or just the players with just one hit on the database

```
members = Team.objects.get(pk='someteam').members
players = Team.objects.get(pk='someteam').members.players()
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution, I will compare it with the solution of Sergey Gornostaev ! Thank you !